# Using browser-supplied 3rd party oauth2 token in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0

I'm looking for a nodejs Express library for this:

- A 3rd party site `Acme` has a protected GET API `https://example.com/getdata`, and it's an OAuth2 server.
- My web app calls `getdata`, which forces it to authenticate.
- Afterwards, my web app POSTs some data to **my own** server.
- My server also needs to call Acme's `getdata`, impersonating the current user. I cannot trust the data from my web app.
- If the call to Acme's `getdata` fails on my nodejs server, it should redirect my web app to authenticate via a popup, and try again.

I'm building a nodejs express service that can make calls to a 3rd party using oauth2 token supplied by the client.  The client side code is already authenticated with the 3rd party, and calls my service the same way as it calls the 3rd party servers.

I am able to do a pass-through token validation using [express-accesstoken-validation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-accesstoken-validation) module, but that only tells me if supplied token is valid.  How would I make a GET request using that token?

Comment: you need to check the 3rd party api documentation for that, they can build the api in any way they like.

Comment: @SebastiánEspinosa I know how to call 3rd party API. I am looking for an easy nodejs lib that would wrap that call with the user-supplied authentication token.

Comment: requestjs or fetch?

Comment: Once authenticated, browser can make  a GET request to receive some data.  I need that same GET request to be made by my nodejs server.  So the browser needs to call my server with the authentication token, so the server can GET data from the 3rd party, impersonating the logged in user.

Comment: BTW, if my server fails the GET, it should tell the browser to authenticate with the 3rd party first, before retrying.